# Facebook search api to get Id of pages by searching name

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am using the Facebook api, endpoint "search", to get id of any page that i search.

API URL: https://graph.facebook.com/search
SEARCH_PARAMS:

- access_token: [User access token]
- q: "Bottom of the Hill"
- type: page

and i'm getting { data: [] } as response every time.

Is this api still valid or working today?
Is there a specific permission i'm missing?
Am i using the correct api?
Is there another way to do this? if so what permission i will need to use it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching

Comment: CBroe When i use this api it gives me this error: (#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.
I already have advance access to pages_read_engagement permission.

Comment: I think you will need to get your app approved for one of the two mentioned features. Facebook does not allow you to access the data of public pages you do not have admin access to any more without either of those.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching` endpoint, but for that you will need have approved one of next features: 'Page Public Content Access' or the 'Page Public Metadata Access'. And both of them are not working in Dev mode at all :)